# Customize the Zend Framework 2 Routers

Tags: zend-framework2, router

I have started the application development with zend framework 2.
For instance, I have the Module named as 'Album'.

And i have the following codes in module.config.php.

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(

            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Album\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

I can access the following urls.

ZF2/album
ZF2/album/album/index

I like to route the url 'ZF2/album/album/view' into ZF2/view-album.

How can i route? Help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the access with the following codes.

```
'view-album' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/view-album[/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Album\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'view-album',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Comment: i can able to get id from view-album url.

Comment: Its not working when i use : `http://www.example.com/Formación` because the controller is static`Formación` . how can i fix it?